# How to use contents = to add to a Scala Panel?

Tags: swing, scala

Sorry this must be a very silly question.. but everywhere I've been seeing Scala code examples where you just do
contents+= on a BoxPanel or some layout Panel. I figured because they have contents as mutable.buffer so you can just add and remove components.

But how do you add a component to Scala Panel? It accepts a seq so do you have to give it a list or something? I know you can just call peer.add but I want to see how Scala code does it. :)

For example contents = new Button {} isn't working.

Sorry for this simple question I'm very new to Scala..

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies. My question now though becomes.. can you ever just have a class extending Panel? Would you be able to set contents for it at all? Or is it never done and everyone always just uses the Panels associated with a layout manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Panel class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.swing.Panel) itself is abstract, meaning it can't be instantiated directly, and is intended as a "base" for concrete implementations of panels.

**It doesn't seem to have a "common" method for adding components probably because each subclass implements its own, sometimes mutually incompatible custom one**:

- `BoxPanel`, as you've noted, [has a settable `Buffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.swing.BoxPanel),
- `FlowPanel` seems to mandate [adding components as constructor arguments](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.swing.FlowPanel),
- `GridBagLayout` and some others [implement addition via the `layout` `Map`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/swing/scala/swing/test/GridBagDemo.scala),
- etc.

As you might see from the above examples, it would be hard to specify what a general "add" method would mean in all of those cases.

**EDIT in response:** of course you can, there's nothing stopping you from subclassing a `Panel` yourself and override the `contents` method, e.g.:

```
val myPanel = new Panel() {
                   private val myContents = (new Content += new Button())
                   override def contents = myContents
              }
```

You can also use `Panel` as a type parameter for your methods that process panels in a general way, etc. It's just that you can't have an instance that's **just** a `Panel`, because, again, the class is abstract, so you can't instantiate it.

Note that this is not unique to Scala, if `JPanel` was abstract in Java (like `Component` is) the outcome would be the same.

Comment: So in practice no one actually ever uses the Panel class on its own? We must use one of its concrete implementations?

Comment: @SonicProtein: see final edit, the previous subclass example was incorrect (you need to use the `Content` instance instead of `List`, since `Content` provides the "magic" for interfacing with the peer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a button:

```
val button=new Button{
    text="Click me!"
}
or 

val label=new Label{
    text="Look, i'm a label!"
}
or
object myField extends TextField{ columns=2 }
```

then you just use:

```
contents=new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){
  contents+=button
  border=Swing.EmptyBorder(10,20,10,20)
}
```

or in a more simpler form:

```
 contents=new FlowPanel(){
  contents+=new Label("This is my button:")
  contents+=new Button("Click me!")
  border=Swing.EmptyBorder(10,20,10,20)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this in a class which extends scala.swing.Panel? I did this but it keeps saying value contents_= is not a member of (name of my class which extends Panel). Ahh I see, are you setting the contents for a scala.swing.Frame?

Comment: Yes, this is for scala's frame.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to see how Scala code does it.

https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/blob/v1.0.0-RC2/src/main/scala/scala/swing/Container.scala#L35

I, too, practiced on some Swing code when I first learned some Scala.

Here is a Panel component that renders itself as a simple game grid:

https://github.com/som-snytt/House-of-Mirrors-Fork/blob/act/src/main/scala/hom/LightBox.scala#L286

To see how the Scala and Swing pieces fit together, see `SuperMixin`:

https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/blob/v1.0.0-RC2/src/main/scala/scala/swing/Component.scala#L51

Assembly:

https://github.com/som-snytt/House-of-Mirrors-Fork/blob/act/src/main/scala/hom/HouseOfMirrors.scala#L18

This is what you asked about directly:

https://github.com/som-snytt/House-of-Mirrors-Fork/blob/act/src/main/scala/hom/HouseOfMirrors.scala#L45